# Passing event listener state as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React code, I'm using Babel's stage 3 class properties, which doesn't need a constructor for declaring states and event listeners. The parent component has two states: `color` and `listener`. The problem now is, the `this.state.listener`, which is passed as `clickEvent` prop, is NOT working.

The code below is supposed to change the color of the button from white to black and vice versa on every click.

```
const Button = props => {
  const { background, clickEvent } = props;
  const styles = {
    background,
    color: background === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000'
  };

  return <button style={styles} onClick={clickEvent}>Change color</button>
}



export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    color: '#fff',
    listener: this.changeColor
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      color: state.color === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000'
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { color, listener } = this.state;

    return (
      <Button background={color} clickEvent={listener} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't define listener on state. Just do `<Button background={color} clickEvent={this. changeColor} />`

Answer (score 2):

You should not store functions in your state, juste variables. You should pass the `changeColor` functions to the child props like this:

```
const Button = props => {
  const { background, clickEvent } = props;
  const styles = {
    background,
    color: background === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000'
  };

  return <button style={styles} onClick={clickEvent}>Change color</button>
}



export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    color: '#fff',
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      color: state.color === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000'
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { color } = this.state;

    return (
      <Button background={color} clickEvent={this.changeColor} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I read an example in React docs about Context where an event listener state is being passed as prop to a child component. That's what I'm trying to imitate, but in stage-3 way (no constructor).

Comment: I really doubt they added that in their official doc, look like an anti-pattern.

Comment: I think so, too. Thanks, btw

Answer (score 0):

Just directly use that method, like so:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    color: '#fff'
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      color: state.color === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000'
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { color, listener } = this.state;

    return (
      <Button background={color} clickEvent={this.changeColor} /> //fixed
    )
  }
}
```

We don't need to make it a `state` property.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is you're doing things in the wrong order. You declare this.state first, and this.changeColor later, so you're trying to access this.changeColor before it is defined. So if you wanted to continue storing it in state, which i agree with others is probably unnecessary, you will need to swap their order:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      color: state.color === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000'
    }))
  }

  state = {
    color: '#fff',
    listener: this.changeColor
  }

  render() {
    const { color, listener } = this.state;

    return (
      <Button background={color} clickEvent={listener} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: No, order is not important here. I doesn't work for some other reason.

Comment: Yes, it is. The transpiled version of the code takes both of the class properties,  moves them into the constructor, and keeps them in the order they are written. Referencing this.changeColor before it has been defined will result in this.state.listener being `undefined`. You can play around with this at babeljs.io/repl. Make sure to include babel-plugin-transform-class-properties, and i'd recommend using the es2016 preset to make it easier to follow the transpiled code.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice `changeColor` was property too, thought it was a method.